# Using server.inject in regular production use cases - bad idea or good idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Here's my default use case: I'm thinking about serving some of my REST resources over a socket.io layer instead of over http (since I end up needing to serve a lot of small api requests to render a typical page, and they're all over https, which has extra handshaking issues).

I'm still not sure this is a good idea in general (and have been looking at http2.0 as well). In the short term, I don't want to migrate off of hapijs *or* rewrite a ton of modular code, but I *do* want to try out making this work on some test servers to see how well it performs.

So I wrote a super-basic socket.io event handler that just takes requests off of the websocket event emitter and repackages them into hapi via a `server.inject` call:

```
module.exports = {
  addSocket: function(sock) {
    sock.on('rest:get:request', function(sock) {
      return function(url) {
        console.log(url);
        hapi.inject({url: url, credentials: {user: sock.user}}, function(res) {
          sock.emit('rest:get:response', url, res.payload);
        });
      };
    })(sock);
  }
};
```

So, all it really does is make sure the authentication object is set up (I have previously authenticated the user on the socket) and then inject a GET request to the server.

*Usually*, it seems like `server.inject` is used for testing, but this seems like a perfectly cromulent plan, unless (of course), it's super-slow or a bad idea for reasons I haven't foreseen. Hence: my question.

Comment: fwiw, I'm not wild about these "suggested edits" over which I had no say - this is strictly a hapi.js performance / usage question. I also didn't flag the ? as socket.io.

Comment: So to clarify: this is a question about the performance of `server.inject` in production on hapi.js - typically something that's just used during testing. Is it a Bad Idea to use this outside of testing for everyday stuff?

Comment: My anecdote isn't worth a full answer, but we use server.inject in production without issues.  Our application has two servers, one of which answers SOAP responses, but really just passes the payload to the prefered REST endpoint via `server.select("rest").inject ...`

Answer (score 2):

`Server.inject` is a great way of encapsulating sub requests however it can become more complicated than necessary though. A lighter approach would be to use shared handler functions and run them as [pre-handlers](http://hapijs.com/api#route-prerequisites).

What's nice about the pre handlers is that you can run them in parellel if needed.

One use case where I have used `server.inject` (other than in tests) is for a health check route. I'd have a route `/health-check/db` and `/health-check/queue`. I'd then have a `/health-check` route which encapsulated all of them. But again, this could have been completed with shared route handlers.

I had a lengthy discussion on the gitter channel the other day about this and my understanding is that it is neither good nor bad.

I guess a really good use case would be if you have multiple teams building plugins which expose routes and you want to use one of those routes in your plugin. You don't care about the implementation; you can just *call* the route.

Anothe reason for using `server.inject` is that it includes the validation steps provided by the route so you only need to have your resource defined in one place.